# How can I get unity3d working with my gtx570?

Tags: unity, 11.10, nvidia

Using a fresh install of 11.10; I've literally done *NOTHING* other than install the nvidia drivers.

It may be worthing noting that jockey-gtk did not offer me a proprietary driver to install.

After installing the nvidia drivers with the following statments:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

jockey now shows that the proprietary nvidia driver is installed and in use; I can use the nvidia settings gui fine; glxinfo | grep gl shows:

```
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, 
    GL_NV_texture_multisample, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_NV_texture_shader,
```

Tried to force unity via adding:

```
UNITY_FORCE_START
```

to /etc/environment, which ended up with being left with just a wallpaper;

So obviously the unity WM can't run; I don't get any errors messages; I've googled to try and find where whatever the hell this new gdm logs to no avail.

Another probably useful tidbit:

Using:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

causes a segmentation fault; No information is provided before that either, so that is also useless.

What can I do..?

Comment: What does `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test  -p` say?

Comment: @Bryce Sorry about that, where I said: Using /usr/lib/nux/unity-support-manager -p causes a segmentation fault; I meant that I used: /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p; As such, unity_support_test -p says nothing, it segfaults.

Comment: Ok, well I think /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p failing is likely why unity isn't starting up.  A backtrace might give some clues (i.e. gdb /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test ; run -p ; bt full)

Comment: Also, your /var/log/Xorg.0.log might shed some light on the situation.  It sounds like your GLX module is loaded properly but it's possibly the log will show a revealing error message.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards